# How can I renew an IP address?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I'd like to know how I can get a new IP address (besides opening and closing the TOR browser)

Comment: The onion left to the URL bar can give you a new identity, not necessarily a new IP address as you may end up with the same exit.

Answer (score 1):

**Windows**

Right click the onion icon in Windows Notification Area, and Select "New Identity".

.

**Android**

Go to the Orbot app, and on the big power icon swipe horizontally.

.

**Ubuntu**

Click the onion icon in Tor browser, and Select "New Identity".